# With meteor.js and mongo, please show me the best way to organize a categories collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm coming from the SQL world, so naturally mongo / noSQL has been an adventure.

I'm building a page to add/edit categories, that "posts" will later be assigned to.

What I've basically created is this:

```
{
    _id: "asdf234ljsf",
    title: "CategoryOne",
    sortorder: 1,
    active: true,
    children: [
        {
            title: ChildOne,
            sortorder: 1,
            active: true
        },
        {
            title: ChildTwo,
            sortorder: 2,
            active: true
        }
    ]
}
```

So later, when creating a "post" I would assign that post to one or more parent categories, as well as optionally one or more child categories within the selected parent categories. Visitors to the site if they clicked on a parent category, it would show all posts within that parent category, and if they select a child category, it will only show posts within that child category.

The logic is obvious and simple, but in SQL I would have created tables like this:

```
table_Category ( CategoryID, Title, Sort, Active )
table_Category_Children ( ChildID, ParentID, Title, Sort, Active )
```

I've been reading the Discover Meteor book and it mentions that Meteor gives us many tools that work a lot better when operating at the collection level, as well as how the DDP operates at the top level of a document, meaning if something small changed down in a sub collection or array, potentially unneeded data will be sent back to all connected/subscribed clients.

So, this makes me think I should be organizing the categories like this:

```
Collection for parent categories

{
    _id: "someid",
    title: "CategoryOne"
    sortorder: 1,
    active: true
},
{
    _id: "someid",
    title: "CategoryTwo"
    sortorder: 1,
    active: true
}

Collection for Child Categories

{
    _id: "someid",
    parent: "idofparent"
    title: "ChildOne"
    sortorder: 1,
    active: true
},
{
    _id: "someid",
    parent: "idofparent"
    title: "ChildTwo"
    sortorder: 1,
    active: true
}
```

Or, perhaps its better like this:

```
Collection for parent categories

{
    _id: "someid",
    title: "CategoryOne"
    sortorder: 1,
    active: true,
    children: [ { id: "childid" }, ... ]
}
```

I think understanding a best practice/method for Meteor and Mongo in this scenario will help me greatly across the board.

So conclusion: I have an admin page where I add/edit these categories. When clients create a post, they'll select the parent and child categories suitable for their post and make sure that I organize it properly from the beginning. Changing my thinking process from a traditional RDBMS to NoSQL is a big jump.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores all data in documents. This is a fundamental difference from relational database like SQL.

Imagine if you have 100 parent categories and 1000 child categories, once you update a parent category it will affect all linked child category's "idofparent", in a reactive way. In short, it's not sustainable.

Try to think of a way to avoid JOIN SQL equivalent in MongoDB.
Restructure you data perhaps similar to this way:

One big collection for all categories:

```
{
    _id: id,
    title: title,
    sortorder: 1,
    active: 1,
    class: "parent > child" // make this as a field 
    ...
}

// class can be "parent1", "parent2", "parent1 > child1" ... you get the idea
```

so each document store is completely individual.
Or if you absolutely need JOIN relational data structure, I don't think MongoDB is the right choice for you.